# What is the forward slash in the Java Classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

Okay, I am having a lot of confusion regarding classpaths and jars. I have a runnable jar that is accessing a folder with property files outside of the jar. Now what I can't understand is that why I need to access the resources by using a forward slash like the following-:

```
InputStream s = (InputStream)
                    Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("/bar.properties");
```

What does the forward slash mean? Does it mean starting at the root of the classpath? Isn't that what happens by default?

I have already modified the classpath in the manifest file before running the jar with the following line-:

```
Class-Path: folder/
```

I needed to have a slash at the end of folder otherwise it was not working correctly. So why is there forward slashes needed both in the manifest file and in the getResourceAsStream call?

Comment: Read the docs for Class.getResourceAsStream: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String- (And imagine if your `Foo` class were in a package of `x.y`...)

Comment: With the Java libraries for dealing with files, you can safely use / (slash, not backslash) on all platforms. The library code handles translating things into platform-specific paths internally.

Comment: @JonSkeet So am I correct in saying that when I use slash it will not use the package name ? So instead for searching in package x.y it will search in the directory where package x.y is located ? But then that begs the question how is my jar able to find something at `folder/`

Comment: @JonSkeet My question simply is that if my classpath is not explicitly set where is the resource searched for when using the forward slash ? And if it is set then where is the resource searched for ?

Comment: @DeedarAliBrohi These are URLs, not filenames, and resources, not files. Backslashes would never be correct in the first place. The question is not about backslashes.

Comment: The slash is about what fully-qualified resource name you're looking for - not really about the classpath at all.